# Multiple Select2 tags Issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to provide pillboxes tags for a multiple select in our project, but in Internet Explorer, if the user types in a few characters, those characters are encapsulated as a tag and the user cannot finish typing the custom tag. I was wondering if there are any workarounds. Here is some code that replicates the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>My Select2 Example</title>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        Selections:
        <select id="example1">
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
            <option>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example1').select2({
        //allowClear: true,
        //placeholder: '',
        tags: true,
        //tokenSeparators: [',', ';', '\n', '\t',' '],
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        // selectOnClose: true,
        multiple: true
    });
});
```

If you try typing 'abcdefghijk' in the box, unless you can type in extremely fast, you are prevented from typing the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and stumbled upon this question while looking for a solution. Seems like [it was a Bug](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4398) which is fixed in Version 4.0.6.